# Change Header content depending if logged in or out

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

I want to display on the Header the button "Login" when the user is logged out, and "Logout" when the user is logged in.

I decided to use Redux for this with the stated "loggedIn". This works fine, except when I reload the page. The "loggedIn" is reset to its default (false).

Is Redux a good approach for this? Note: I am using JWT for authentification

Comment: On refresh, your page will be reloaded from server. Whether you use local state or redux, it is only active on the client side state, the moment you refresh, a new page is loaded from the server and you will lose all your client state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app scale, for bigger app use redux to prevent props drilling.